htaccess - redirect domain to a specific page, unless a path is spefcified
I have an old url that I need to redirect to a specific page on my new site -- this part is working fine. That code is below.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldurl.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldurl.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldurl.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldurl.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newurl.com/the/old/page/$1 [R=301,L]

The issue is that occasionally I need to use a specific path from the old site and point it at a different url on the new site.
Is there a way to redirect to a specific page when the old url has no path specified, but when there is a path, to keep it and add it to the new url?
so oldurl.com ==> newurl.com/the/old/page
but oldurl.com/anything-else ==> newurl.com/anything-else

Sure this is possible. In general you simply implement more specific redirection rules before (so further up) than more general rules. To give a specific answer you will have to revise your question though (there is an "edit" button). Currently it is not really clear what you want to treat as exception. Your current rule already preserves and path component when redirecting to the new domain name. This is in contrast to what you write what is missing. Also it is not really clear what you mean by "segments" here.

@arkascha -- I only want to redirect to the specific url in my current redirect when people go to oldurl.com without any additional path. If there are any url segments after the .com, I want them appended to newurl.com (and not to the longer url path that is specified in the current redirect). So basically, the generic old url should go to the specific new url, but a specific old url should go to the new url with the old url's path appended.

And what keeps you from adding a redirection rule for that the way I explained above?

"No path" means, the value RewriteRule will check against, will simply be an empty string (when configured in .htaccess context; when done via the server configuration, then it would be a single /) - so just check for exactly that value, RewriteRule ^$ https://new-specific-url [...]

Let's carry together what we concluded in the comments to the question that help to understand what exactly you want to achieve ...
I assume you serve both domains (oldurl.com and newurl.com) from the same server (since you added RewriteCond statements). I took the liberty to simplify them a bit. If those rules get applied on a server that only responds to requests to oldurl.com and oldurl.org then you can simply omit those conditions.
The existing RewriteRule is a bit miss leading in your question. It captures the path of the requested URL and appends it to the target URL. Which is NOT what you want, according to your comment. So I changed it.
RewriteEngine on

# redirect https://oldurl.com/ to https://new-specific-url/the/old/page/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldurl\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldurl.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://new-specific-url/the/old/page/ [R=301,L]

# redirect https://oldurl.com/<anything> to https://new-specific-url/<anything>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldurl\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldurl.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://newurl.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

As explained in my first comment the more specific rule comes first (so further up in the file). Think of it as an exception. After that follows the general fallback rule.
I used ^/?$ as matching pattern in the first rule (as opposed to just ^$ as C3roe suggested it in his comment). Comes out the same here, but I personally prefer to implement rules such that they can be used without changing them in the central configuration or in distributed configuration files. If in doubt you should always prefer the central configuration, if you have access to that . Otherwise, so if you are using a cheap hosting provider for example, you can use distributed configuration files, if that feature is enabled for that location , though that comes with a few disadvantages.
An alternative to the second rule is something like RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ https://newurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]. It explicitly captures the requested path in the matching pattern and reuses the captured sequence. But since that is already contained in the special variable %{REQUEST_URI} I personally prefer that one.
Please take the time to actually understand the implementation. Do not blindly copy it. You want to learn.
You can play around with above suggestion using a simple test site.

Thank you. I was confused about two things -- which rule was more specific, and also thinking that the difference between the two redirects would be in the conditions and not just in the rule itself. I hadn't seen that test site before. That is a huge help in seeing what is actually going on.

@artmem If you want to examine in detail what conditions and rules do, then I recommend to enable rewrite logging (see the documentation on how to do that). It allows you to follow what is going on inside your rewriting engine on a step by step base.
